# Bind9 on a dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I am using bind9 on a dedicated vps with ip: xx.xx.xx.xx

And i have vps server with webserver and its ip: yy.yy.yy.yy

Question: it is correct to point nameservers, e.g. ns1.domain.com/ns2.domain.com to bind9 server with following ip: xx.xx.xx.xx then on bind9 server create a zone file with a following values:

```
; BIND data file for domain.com
;
;$TTL 14400
$TTL 3600
@ IN SOA dns1.domain.com. srv.domain.com. (
2014241000 ; Serial
7200 ; Refresh
120 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800) ; Default TTL
;
@ IN NS dns1.domain.com.
@ IN NS dns2.domain.com.

@ IN MX 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ IN MX 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ IN MX 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ IN MX 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@ IN MX 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

mail IN CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com.

@ IN A yy.yy.yy.yy

dns1 IN A xx.xx.xx.xx
dns2 IN A xx.xx.xx.xx
www IN A yy.yy.yy.yy
ftp IN A yy.yy.yy.yy
@ IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:yy.yy.yy.yy include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:_spf.google.com ?all"
```

In a short: pointing nameserver (ns1,ns2) to bind (DNS server) then pointing bind to another server (webserver without bind).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work.
You will need to make sure that the glue records are in place with your domain registry.
This is explained in more detail and with examples [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/ns.html).

Comment: Thanks, but your link gave me an error. How can i check glue records?

Comment: Martin, reread the question, particularly the line "*pointing nameserver to bind then pointing bind to another server*".  As I understand it, the OP wants to re-delegate the zone *without* altering the glue records, and I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @MadHatter, so it won't work in my case? What's the point of bind server on a dedicated server?

Comment: Just as Martin says, you point your glue records at it, and it serves your zone.  By the way, it's **completely** pointless to redact the zone in this question, as nameservers and the RRs they serve are a matter of public record.  If you go back and edit your zone into your question, it may help us get to an answer more quickly.